# Sort 2D string array based on another string array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

As the title states, I wish to implement a method that would allow me to sort a 2d array given a column based on an array e.g. sort 2d array by column 2 based on the order of the array.

```
String[][] a1 = new String[][]{
  {x,dog,x}
  {x,monkey,x}
  {x,cat,x}
}
//x being a random string

String[] a2 = new String[]{dog,cat,monkey};

//Output should be:
 a1 = {
  {x,dog,x}
  {x,cat,x}
  {x,monkey,x}
 }
```

I'm not sure what direction to go from this point, I have looked at comparator but I'm not sure how I would implement it in this scenario. Any guidance to help me accomplish this is appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest reading more about the Comparator class. That's what you'll want to do here. Write a couple simple examples with the Comparator first. For example: create an object like Car with fields like Color and Year, then use a comparator to sort a list of these objects by one field, then the other. Then you will clearly see how to apply this to your current problem.

Comment: It is possible to swap all the concerned cells with a bit of logic.

Comment: @coding97 I understand you want to sort a1 by the second column.... But what's the purpose of the a2 array??

Comment: @Highbrainer, oops that's a bad example I gave, I wanted it sorted by the order of the a2 regardless of alphabetical order. if that makes any sense

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Comparator<String[]>` that depends on `a2` array:

```
String[] a2 = new String[]{"dog", "cat", "monkey"};

Comparator<String[]> comparator = (arr1, arr2) -> {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(a2);

    int index1 = list.indexOf(arr1[1]);
    int index2 = list.indexOf(arr2[1]);

    return Integer.compare(index1, index2);
};

Arrays.sort(a1, comparator);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cat, dog and monkey as String objects:

```
  Arrays.stream(a1).sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> -1 * Arrays.asList(a2).indexOf(s[1]))).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Ruslan answer, Comparator is the right way to go, but you probably won't want to do an indexof for every comparison in the sort, so you want to start by mapping your reference string to a reverse index:

```
    String[] a2 = new String[]{"dog", "cat", "monkey"};
    Map<String, Integer> order = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
      order.put(a2[i], i);
    }

    Comparator<String[]> comparator = (arr1, arr2) -> {
      int index1 = order.get(arr1[1]);
      int index2 = order.get(arr2[1]);

      return Integer.compare(index1, index2);
    };

    Arrays.sort(a1, comparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that should help you.
It sort the array according the string number two, in the order provided by a2. If seconds strings are the same, it compares on first string and then on third strings. 
Watch out it does check for null strings.

The important part is this :

```java
 @Override
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {      
        int score1 = types.indexOf(o1[1])-types.indexOf(o2[1]);
        if(score1!=0) {
            return score1;
        }

        int score2 = o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
        if(score2!=0) {
            return score2;
        }

        int score3 = o1[2].compareTo(o2[2]);
        return score3;
    }
```

See :

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SpecialComparatorMain implements Comparator<String[]> {

    private List<String> types;

    public SpecialComparatorMain(List<String> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a2 = new String[]{"dog","cat","monkey"};
        String[][] a1 = new String[][]{
              {"z","dog","x"},
              {"y","monkey","x"},
              {"x","cat","x"},
              {"x","monkey","x"},
              {"y","cat","x"},
              {"z","monkey","z"},
              {"z","monkey","y"},
              {"z","monkey","x"},
            };
            //x being a random string

            System.out.println("Before");
            Stream.of(a1).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);

            Arrays.sort(a1, new SpecialComparatorMain(Arrays.asList(a2)));

            System.out.println("After");
            Stream.of(a1).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {      
        int score1 = types.indexOf(o1[1])-types.indexOf(o2[1]);
        if(score1!=0) {
            return score1;
        }

        int score2 = o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
        if(score2!=0) {
            return score2;
        }

        int score3 = o1[2].compareTo(o2[2]);
        return score3;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Before
[z, dog, x]
[y, monkey, x]
[x, cat, x]
[x, monkey, x]
[y, cat, x]
[z, monkey, z]
[z, monkey, y]
[z, monkey, x]

After
[z, dog, x]
[x, cat, x]
[y, cat, x]
[x, monkey, x]
[y, monkey, x]
[z, monkey, x]
[z, monkey, y]
[z, monkey, z]
```

HTH!